# Passing many variables/parameters from Controller to View

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

How do i pass many parameters to View from Controller?

I need to, depending on controller, show pictures on website. I am trying to pass their adresses to View but I don't think it is effective.

In addition i don't know if there will be 5 of them or 5 blocks of 50, I do have to have also some kind of counter.

The ideal solution would be, if I can pass whole object to View but I don't know if it is possible and if it is, how to do this.

Comment: "whole object" would be the `model` part of `model-view-controller`. You should research some basic MVC tutorials.

Comment: Use a viewmodel, you can put anything you like into a class and send it to the view

Comment: Didn't think i can do that. Thanks, I am getting down to work!

Comment: Also, remove `asp-classic` tag or explain why it is there.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an ViewModel and then in the controller pass for example a List of Images to the view.

I am not sure how do you store the images because you do not refer that in your question but you can for example store them in the file system and then in the controller just make a list of paths to those images.

Alternatively you can store the images in the database and then in the controler get them from the database and add them to the ViewModel.

If you need more help just let me know.